# Custom Caption for ButtonSet

Tags: button, dialog, google-closure, google-closure-library

How can I change the caption (text) of the **buttons** of any `ButtonSet` in **Google Closure Library** `goog.ui.Dialog` ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like buttonset objects have an addButton function, which takes an object as the first parameter: @param {!{key: string, caption: string}}

So, all you have to do is create on-the-fly objects with a key (the data behind the button) and caption (the actual label of the button)

```
var dialog = new goog.ui.Dialog();
dialog.setContent("Content");

// create a button set
var buttonset = new goog.ui.Dialog.ButtonSet();
buttonset.addButton({key: "next", caption: "Next"});
buttonset.addButton({key: "previous", caption: "Previous"});
dialog.setButtonSet(buttonset);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dialog1 = new goog.ui.Dialog();
dialog1.setContent('<img src="css/img/warning.png" style="float: right"/>' +
'<div>It is a warning message!</div>');
dialog1.setTitle('Warning');
dialog1.setButtonSet(goog.ui.Dialog.ButtonSet.OK);
dialog1.setVisible(true);
var btnOk = dialog1.getButtonSet().getAllButtons()[0];
btnOk.innerHTML = 'Custome OK';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change default captions:

```
goog.ui.Dialog.ButtonSet.DefaultButtons.CANCEL.caption = 'anuluj';
goog.ui.Dialog.ButtonSet.DefaultButtons.OK.caption = 'confirm';
```